# Using axios.delete() to adjust json file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, json-server

I'm kinda newbie at using axios and react with json-server. and what I did is to delete certain array in my json file and I did make it work somehow, below is the code what I did.

```
  function postDelete() {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/posts/${Number(pathUrl)}`)
    navigate('/');
  }
```

it triggers by onclick and as you can see it goes to my URL and if "id" params matches the ${Number(pathUrl)} it deletes.

and after writing this down, I found out this code would not be safe to use because someone can see and get my json server url.

is there more effective ways to implement this?

ps. sorry for bad english

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by `I found out this code would not be safe to use because someone can see and get my json server url.`?

Comment: @KevinYobeth since those url is not encrypted, so anyone can check the location of data sets(which is json file location url) and modify to get other data that are not allowed to access. for example, data sets like password and id of certain users? although it's localhost for now.

Comment: why whould you use json server for your production environment? Json server itself state that it's a `quick back-end for prototyping and mocking.` If you want to use it on production, try using a real backend with authentication or Backend as a service such as firebase or supabase.